# Methods to control for false omission rate?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, type-i-and-ii-errors, false-discovery-rate

What methods are available to control for false omission rate in multiple comparisons, similar to the way Benjamini-Hochberg controls for false discovery rate?

The goal is to filter out obvious negatives while minimizing discarding of potential positives, and use the result as input to the next stage of an analysis pipeline which will further refine the result using other methods.

Comment: Can you explain what is*false omission rate*?

Comment: Rate of type II errors, the negative analog of FDR. As defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values#false_omission_rate): FOR = False negatives / (True negatives + False negatives)